# Install path for cmake modules

Tags: cmake

So if I'm making a package with cmake/cpack, there must be a variable already set in cmake that tells it where to put the *.cmake files that will be used by find_package for my module...right?

What's that variable?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), it is either `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, but I would not recommend that, otherwise you can put your `<name>-config.cmake` files anywhere, as long as you specify the path in your `find_package` call.

Otherwise system-wide paths might be set, being `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH` and`CMAKE_SYSTEM_APPBUNDLE_PATH`.

from the documentation (removed unnecessary information):

```
find_package(<package> ...
         [CONFIG]
         ...
         [NAMES name1 [name2 ...]]
         [CONFIGS config1 [config2 ...]]
         [HINTS path1 [path2 ... ]]
         [PATHS path1 [path2 ... ]]
         [PATH_SUFFIXES suffix1 [suffix2 ...]]
         ...)
```

It will search for `<NAMES>-config.cmake` in all `PATHS` and all `HINTS` (in that order), as well as predefines CMAKE Paths.

The exact search order (from the documentation cited above):

> 1. Search paths specified in cmake-specific cache variables. These are intended to be used on the command line with a -DVAR=value. This can be skipped if NO_CMAKE_PATH is passed
> 2. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables. These are intended to be set in the user’s shell configuration. This can be skipped if NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH is passed
> 3. Search paths specified by the HINTS option. These should be paths computed by system introspection, such as a hint provided by the location of another item already found. Hard-coded guesses should be specified with the PATHS option.
> 4. Search the standard system environment variables. This can be skipped if NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH is passed. Path entries ending in /bin or /sbin are automatically converted to their parent directories

Comment: Nope.  CMAKE_MODULE_PATH is unavailable as a variable.  Attempts to pass it to message() result in failure: message called with incorrect number of arguments.  This is what you get when the variable is unset.

Comment: @CrazyEddie if it is not set you can either set it or put your files where ever you want, as long as you specify in the `find_package` call. Usually the path is set during configuration, at least in most projects I've seen.

Comment: So...I'm not looking for a way to put the cmake file somewhere and configure dependents to add that location to their search path.  That kind of nullifies the point.  I want to configure the installer to put the module file in a location that cmake will find it, with a way for the user to override that setting.

Comment: @CrazyEddie and neither `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` nor `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` are set for your CMake?

Comment: @CrazyEddie ok, but your system `PATH` is set, right? Because that's a default search directory for CMake aswell.

Comment: @Theolodis Note that OP is interested in the path to use to do `install(...)`. Not for the `find_package()` which is automatic if you install the files in the right place to start with.

Answer (score 0):

### The Variable

I've found the variable named `CMAKE_ROOT` to include the path to the default `cmake` modules:

```
CMAKE_ROOT=/usr/share/cmake-3.10
```

This path is what it is set to under Ubuntu 18.04 which is correct compared to the `cmake` version on that platform:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

### How do you find such *hidden* variables?

A while back, I *stole* a piece of code I found on stackoverflow which I can use to display all the variables at a given point in the processing of my CMakeLists.txt files. I create a command I called [DumpCMakeVariables](https://github.com/m2osw/snapcmakemodules/blob/main/Modules/DumpCMakeVariablesConfig.cmake).

To use it (assuming the Modules directory is somehow accessible):

```
find_package(DumpCMakeVariables)

DumpCMakeVariables()
```

If you have an idea of the variable name, then you can include a valid regular expression as the parameter of that function. To only list variables that start with "CMAKE_" write:

```
DumpCMakeVariables("^CMAKE_")
```

Then re-run your configuration process, something like this:

```
cmake <path to source> | less -S
```

and search for a specific variable or what your think the value should be. In out case here:

```
/usr.share.cmake
```

That will eventually point us to `CMAKE_ROOT`.

### Other Installation Path

Note that I also install files directly under:

```
/usr/share/cmake/<name>/<name>Config.cmake
```

And if you want to include a version:

```
/usr/share/cmake/<name>/<name>ConfigVersion.cmake
```

where `<name>` is generally Camel Case.

Having such a directory allows you to have many sub-`.cmake` files that your main configuration uses to find this or that. So it is a way to make it much cleaner if you need many files instead of just one.

That being, that `/usr/share/cmake` directory works great. However, certain types of modules should certainly be installed under `CMAKE_ROOT` to 100% work as expected.

---

[Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/CMakeLists.txt) also uses that scheme:

```
# This variable is used in some subdirectories, so we need it here, rather
# than later in the install block
set(CATCH_CMAKE_CONFIG_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Catch2")
```